# Text inside blocks in eps file NOT displayed

Tags: beamer, packages

The following code DOES NOT display the text which is inside the blocks in the eps file and this is abnormal. (see image 1 below)

When you comment either of the lines ending by %1 or %2, the code DOES display the text inside the blocks.  So what's wrong? (see image 2 below)

I was unable to upload the eps file, in case someone wants to reproduce the abnormal behavior (bug?)?

It was quite difficult to isolate this code in a file of more than 1000 lines.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mbeode<presentation> {\usetheme{Darmstadt}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}        %1

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\textsc{\textbf{D}}$     %2
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Schema_conducteur_1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Fonts in graphics can sometimes conflict or be affected by fonts in the main document. And dvips is more picky than pdflatex. In your case I would guess that the eps doesn't embed the font it uses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you make your comment here an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Fonts in graphics can sometimes conflict or be affected by fonts in the main document. And dvips is more picky than pdflatex. In your case I would guess that the eps doesn't embed the font it uses.